# Why a single IBAction can not be associated with UIButton in xib file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

An outlet property and an IBAction are declared in an UIViewController. UILabel view in xib file can be linked to outlet, However when I drag UIButton in same xib file holding control toward File Owner (which set UIViewController class already) there is no popup window show IBAction to associate. Adding another IBAction with different name, the second one appears in popup window when I do same dragging.

I'm wondering if there should be more than one IBAction declared in UIViewController? Why? My code is below:

```
@interface BNRReminderViewController()  
//this outlet is linked to an UIView successfully
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;

@end

@implementation BNRReminderViewController:UIViewController


//doesn't appear in popup window
-(IBAction)addReminder:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *date=self.datePicker.date;
    NSLog(@"Seeting a reminder for %@", date);
}

//shows up in popup window and can be associated to a UIButton
-(IBAction)addReminder1:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *date=self.datePicker.date;
    NSLog(@"Seeting a reminder for %@", date);  
}

@end
```

Comment: Is the action method declared in the header file?

Comment: as @trojanfoe indicated, it would be helpful if you posted the code from your .h file as well.

Comment: Sometimes, simple things like compiling your app or restarting Xcode can help with this sort of thing.

Comment: @trojanfoe, nope. it is only in .m file. I'm sure it is not necessary to declare in header file. I copy another sample project where IBAction method written only in .m file without declaration in .h file but works fine to associated with a Button in xib file.

Comment: besides the thing confused me most is only addReminder1 appears in association box while addReminder not....is there any difference between these 2 methods except their name? Neither in .h file...

Comment: Yeah I think you are right about it not needing to be in the header file.  It's almost as if `addReminder` is a reserved word or something, though I couldn't find any evidence to that effect.

Comment: @trojanfoe&Bek, sorry for confusing your guys. Actually I found there is a defect in implementation file. I should put base class name after the class name following implementation tag. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

@implementation BNRReminderViewController<strike>:UIViewController</strike>

Strike out base class name would resolve the problem.